# C# Parallel.Foreach, New Class and Static voids./strings

Tags: c#

I'm using a `Parallel.ForEach` to call and create a new class.

```
Parallel.ForEach(urlTable.AsEnumerable(),drow =>
        {
            using (var WCC = new MasterCrawlerClass() )
            {
                WCC.MasterCrawlBegin(drow);
            }
        });
```

`MasterCrawlerClass` contains `private static voids` and `private static string`.  I guess my question is this.  Since I am calling a new class in my `foreach`, are all my `voids`/`strings` in that new class instance safe?

```
class MasterCrawlerClass : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        GC.Collect();
    }
    public static void SetNewProxy()
    {
        string mysql_Proxyserver_ProxyPort = "select ProxyServer,ProxyPort,ResponseTime FROM proxies.tblproxies where Active = 1 and DateTested >= Date_sub(CurDate(),INTERVAL 2 day) and ResponseTime <= 3 order by Rand() limit 1";
        DataTable proxyDT = new DataTable();
        proxyDT = DTTable(mysql_Proxyserver_ProxyPort, "mysql_Proxyserver_ProxyPort");
        ProxyServer = proxyDT.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
        ProxyPort = Convert.ToInt32(proxyDT.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString());
    }

    private static string HTMLModelProcess(string inputString)
    {
        string returnString = string.Empty;
        string ModelString = inputString.Replace("Certified", "").Replace("Used", "").Trim();
        string[] makeModelSplit = ModelString.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 4);
        returnString = makeModelSplit[2];
        return returnString;

    }
    private static string ProxyServer { get; set; }
    private static int ProxyPort { get; set; }

}

private static DataTable DTTable(string mysqlQuery, string queryName)
    {
        DataTable DTTableTable = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter DataDTTables = new MySqlDataAdapter(mysqlQuery, MySQLProcessing.MySQLStatic.Connection);
            DataTable DataDTTablesDT = new DataTable();
            DataDTTables.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 240000;
            DataDTTables.Fill(DataDTTablesDT);
            DTTableTable = DataDTTablesDT;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            GenericLogging("Failed MySQLquery: " + ex.Message.ToString(), "MySQLProcessor", "DTTable", "", "MysqlError", "", queryName, mysqlQuery);

        }
        return DTTableTable;
    }
```

The MysqlProcessing.Mysqlstatic.Connection is set before the Parallel and should NEVER change.

This is a few more `voids` and some more `strings`.  I dont understand Threading completely yet, so I'm trying to work my way through it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "contains private static voids and private static string"? Please give some sample code.

Comment: Your static methods are not an threading issue.  However, it would be an issue if you had static members (variables) containing data that is modified.

Comment: @Casperah, clearly he does if you look at SetNewProxy().

Comment: @smartcaveman Sorry for the confusion does seeing those chance the answer if they are thread safe?  Please see edit

Comment: @smartcaveman How would I adjust ProxyServer/ ProxyPort?  If you had a sample that would be awesome

Comment: We also need the DTTable method and any other uses of ProxyServer/ProxyPort.  So far, no.

Comment: Mike, maybe it would help for you to post the whole class. Since I can only make assumptions about what ProxyServer and ProxyPort are used for, I have no way of providing an example.

Comment: @smartcaveman the whole class is like 1600 lines, mainly because i consolidated all of my classes into one class thinking that if i called a new instance of one class I would not have to worry about stackoverflows

Comment: @smartcaveman Please see edit which contains DTTable

Comment: The DTTable method looks fine.  The possibility of side effects still depends on whether or how ProxyPort & ProxyServer are used outside of the SetNewProxy() method, as well as where SetNewProxy () is called from

Answer (score 1):

Your HTMLModelProcess is thread safe.  It does not affect any application State.

The SetNewProxy method is not thread safe.  It changes the state of the ProxyServer and ProxyPort, which are shared.  If this behavior is supposed to happen in an instance scope it (and the related state) should be moved to the instance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your question is not very clear, but AFAIU, you want to know, is your class MasterCrawlerClass thread safe (i.e. safe for use with Parallel.ForEach() or other cases were it is accessed by more than one thread) as long as you create a new instance in the delegate that you pass to Parallel.ForEach() (i.e. new instance for each thread).

The answer - if each thread has its own instance of the class - all instance (non-static) fields and properties are safe, but static ones are not necessarily. If you assign them only once - when they are declared or in the static constructor and only read from them after that - it SHOULD be OK. But if you have a function or functions that write to a static member - this access should be synchronized to avoid simultaneous writes or read-writes. [Here is MSDN info info on synchronization - see if "locking" suits your needs.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228964%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Since the class you provided has only static functions and properties - its not clear, why you create a new instance in Parallel.ForEach - all those properties are class level and will lead to same objects in memory and there will be problems if you try to launch your static functions on different threads (unsynchronized concurrent access).

P.S. Note, that if you have a static field or property of some class (reference type) and write one of its fields\properties - its still unsafe - several threads are trying to change the same piece of memory, possibly simultaneously and with unpredictable results.

Comment: even thought it's calling a new instance of the class that contains those?